# node.js with html and mysql array

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I query my db from mysql workbench and I want to use this query to html code

```
connection.query(
    'SELECT dealer_infor.dealer_id, dealer_infor.dealer_branch, dealer_infor.dealer_address, dealer_infor.dealer_tel, dealer_infor.dealer_contact FROM dealer_infor',
    // 'SELECT Bigbike_ID, Bigbike_name, Price FROM bigbike ORDER BY Bigbike_ID',
    function (err, results){
      if (err) throw err;

        res.render('dealer', {dealers: results});
    }
    );

});
```

And I want to use `dealer_branch` number 0 on the array

```
{% for dd in dealers %}
    <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sg1" aria-expanded="true">
        {{dd.dealer_branch[0]}}
    </h4>
{% endfor %}
```

But the result is the only first character of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
{% for dd in dealers %}
    <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sg1" aria-expanded="true">
        {{dd.dealer_branch}}
    </h4>
{% endfor %}
```

or with `.ejs` something like this,

```
<% for(var i = 0;i < dealers.length;i++) { %>
    <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sg1" aria-expanded="true">
        <%=dealers[i].dealer_branch%>
    </h4>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> dealers[dd].dealer_branch

Here

> dd

Gives you index in dealers array.

This is because dd.dealer_branch[0] gives the first char so dont use [0] otherwise you are doing correct

Comment: yeah yeah but i want to use number 1 of array not first char sir. pls help me

Comment: @Oakko sorry i dont understand .Did above thing doesnt work?

Comment: didn't work, In my array is a group of word, I want the all of word not only the first char TT

Comment: What does dealers[dd] gives??

Comment: give a name of company branch

Comment: What does your dealers array get from query ?can you put that here.

Comment: yeah a sec i ill capture my db